# Запуск приложения при ошибке или при выключенном интернете

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, openweathermap

У меня есть приложение, в котором есть погода, которая берется с `OpenWeatherMap`.

Как сделать так, чтобы при ошибке с `OpenWeatherMap` (превышен лимит запросов) и **`при выключенном интернете приложение все равно открывалось`**?

Вот ссылка на само приложение: https://github.com/ivapop1/Weather-PyQt5

Вот скрин ошибки при отсутствии интернет соединения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Оберните проблемный вызов в блок `try/except`

Comment: @CrazyElf я не знаю как именно это сделать.

Comment: @CrazyElf - там не поможет - кривой дизайн класса...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1 .** Вам надо переделать модуль **root.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>from</class>                                   ???  from
 <widget class="QWidget" name="from">                  ???  from
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>370</width>
    <height>535</height>
    ...
```

**`from`** - это зарезервированное слово и абы как и абы где
его использовать нельзя !!!

Я его конвертировал `pyuic5 root.ui -o root_ui.py -x`

и вручную поправил и использовал в приложении !!!

```
#     vvvvvvv
class Ui_Form(object):
#                     vvvv
    def setupUi(self, Form):
#                           vvvv
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(370, 535)
        ...
```

---

**2 .** Обратите **ВНИМАНИЕ** !!!

В модуле **weather.py**

```
...
print(f'\n\n def today(): g = {g.ok} ')                       # +++
if not g.ok:                                                  # +++
    return False                                              # +++
    
...

    print(f'def week(): g = {g.ok}')                     # +++
    if not g.ok:                                         # +++
        return False                                     # +++
...
```

когда нет коннекта возвращаем  **`False`**

---

В модуле **main.py**

```
        ...
        if req_week and req:                        # !!! 
            self.week = req_week
            self.temp = req['temp']
            self.feels = req['feels']
            self.pres = req['pressure']
            self.speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
            self.city = req['city']
            self.type = req['dis']
        else:
            self.mySignal.emit()
        ...
```

**3 .** и другие нужные вещи по тексту.

---

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtTest, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import weather
# ?import time
import datetime
from weather import DAYS 

# +++ pyuic5 root.ui -o root_ui.py -x
from root_ui import Ui_Form                              # +++

#два класса с числами Фобаначе , для правного визуала 
H_show = [
    155,156,157,158,
    160,168,181,202,
    236,291,380,400,
    440,500,535,
]
H_hide = [
    155,156,157,158,
    160,168,181,202,
    236,291,380,400,
    440,500,535,
]

class WeatherData(QThread):
    req = weather.today()
    temp = req['temp']
    feels = req['feels']
    pres = req['pressure']
    speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
    city = req['city']
    type = req['dis']
    week = weather.week()
    
    mySignal = pyqtSignal()                                    # +++

    def __init__(self):
#        QThread.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            req = weather.today()
            req_week = weather.week()
            
            if req_week and req:                        # !!! 
                self.week = req_week
                self.temp = req['temp']
                self.feels = req['feels']
                self.pres = req['pressure']
                self.speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
                self.city = req['city']
                self.type = req['dis']
            else:
                self.mySignal.emit()

#            time.sleep(1800)                 # 
            self.msleep(1000 * 7) # 1000 * 60 * 30 = 1800сек = 30мин


class MyRoot(QWidget, Ui_Form):                               # +++
    def __init__(self):                                       # +++
        super().__init__()                                    # +++
        self.setupUi(self)                                    # +++ 


class App(QWidget):
    show_more = True 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weather = WeatherData()
        self.weather.mySignal.connect(self._error)            # +++ 
        self.weather.start()
        
        self.set()
        self.setData()
        self.setMore()
        
    def _error(self):                                         # +++ 
        print(f'\n"Проверьте доступ в интернет !!!"\n')       # +++ 

    def set(self):
#        self.w_root = uic.loadUi('root.ui')
        self.w_root = MyRoot()
       
        self.w_root.show()                                    # +++ 
        
        self.w_root.btn_more.clicked.connect(self.setHeight)


    #устанавливаем значение на сегодня
    def setData(self):
        self.w_root.l_temp.setText(str(self.weather.temp) + '°C')
        self.w_root.l_fell.setText(self.weather.feels)
        self.w_root.l_pres.setText(self.weather.pres)
        self.w_root.l_wind.setText(self.weather.speed + 'м/с')
        self.w_root.l_city.setText(self.weather.city)
        self.w_root.l_type.setText(self.weather.type)

        #иконка погоды
        px_logo = QPixmap(f'Ok.png')
        self.w_root.l_logo.setPixmap(px_logo)

        #день недели
        today = DAYS[datetime.datetime.today().weekday()]
        self.w_root.l_day.setText(today['title'])
        color = today['color']
        self.w_root.l_day.setStyleSheet(f'color:{color}')

    def setHeight(self):
        if self.w_root.height() >= 300:
            self.show_more = False
        if self.show_more:
            for i in H_hide:
                if self.w_root.height() > i:
                    continue
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                
                QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
# ?                time.sleep(.02)
            self.show_more = False
        else:
            for i in reversed(H_show):
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
# ?                time.sleep(.02)
            self.show_more = True
        App.show_more = self.show_more

    def setMore(self):
        for i in self.weather.week:
            w_day = uic.loadUi('day.ui')
            w_day.setObjectName('w_day_' + str(i['num']))
            w_day.l_title.setText(i['title'])
            w_day.l_temp.setText(str(round(i['temp'])) + '°C')
            w_day.l_type.setText(i['type'])
            w_day.l_title.setStyleSheet('color: ' + i['color'] + '; background-color: none; border: none')
            if i['active']:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid' + i['color'])
            else:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: none')
            self.w_root.box.addWidget(w_day)
        self.w_root.box.addStretch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = App()
    ex.show
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**weather.py**

```
# weather v 1.0
import requests
import geocoder
import datetime

API_KEY = 'cf64041397ba4128f1a2426cd3e11397'
HOST  = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/'
DAYS =  [
        {'num': 0 , 'title':'понедельник', 'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 1 , 'title':'вторник',     'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [1,2,3,4,5,6,0], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 2 , 'title':'среда',       'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [2,3,4,5,6,0,1], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 3 , 'title':'четверг',     'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [3,4,5,6,0,1,2], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 4 , 'title':'пятница',     'active': False , 'color' : '#2d5664', 'order': [4,5,6,0,1,2,3], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 5 , 'title':'суббота',     'active': False , 'color' : '#d0130d', 'order': [5,6,0,1,2,3,4], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
        {'num': 6 , 'title':'воскресенье', 'active': False , 'color' : '#d0130d', 'order': [6,0,1,2,3,4,5], 'temp': 0, 'type': '-'},
]

def today():
    g = geocoder.ip('199.7.157.0')
    print(f'\n\n def today(): g = {g.ok} ')                       # +++
    if not g.ok:                                                  # +++
        return False                                              # +++
            
    city = g.city
    lat = g.lat
    lon = g.lng
    req = requests.get(f'{HOST}weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric&lang=ru').json()
 
    res={
        'city' : req['name'],
        'dis'  : req['weather'][0]['description'],
        'temp' : int(round(req['main']['temp'])),
        'feels': str(round(req['main']['feels_like']))+ '°С',
        'pressure': str(round(req['main']['pressure'] / 1000 * 750 , 2)),
        'wind' : req['wind'],
    }
    return res

def week():
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    DAYS[today.weekday()]['active'] = True

    for i in DAYS:
        if DAYS[today.weekday()]['active']:
            order = DAYS[today.weekday()]['order']
        g = geocoder.ip('199.7.157.0')
        
        print(f'def week(): g = {g.ok}')                     # +++
        if not g.ok:                                         # +++
            return False                                     # +++
        
        city = g.city
        lat  = g.lat
        lon  = g.lng

        req = requests.get(f'{HOST}onecall?/exclude=daily&lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API_KEY}&units=metric&lang=ru').json()
        res = [DAYS[i] for i in order]

        for i in req['daily']:
            index = req['daily'].index(i)
            if index ==7:
                break
            res[index]['temp'] = round(i['temp']['day'])
            res[index]['type'] = i['weather'][0]['description']
        return res
```

**root_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(370, 535)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(370, 154))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(370, 535))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        font.setPointSize(35)
        Form.setFont(font)
        self.l_temp = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_temp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 6, 131, 81))
        self.l_temp.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(131, 80))
        self.l_temp.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(131, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(30)
        self.l_temp.setFont(font)
        self.l_temp.setObjectName("l_temp")
        self.l_city = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_city.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(4, 4, 131, 25))
        self.l_city.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(131, 24))
        self.l_city.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(131, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.l_city.setFont(font)
        self.l_city.setObjectName("l_city")
        self.l_type = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_type.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 63, 175, 25))
        self.l_type.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(175, 24))
        self.l_type.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(175, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        self.l_type.setFont(font)
        self.l_type.setObjectName("l_type")
        self.l_fell = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_fell.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-6, 83, 123, 20))
        self.l_fell.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(123, 19))
        self.l_fell.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(123, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        self.l_fell.setFont(font)
        self.l_fell.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.l_fell.setObjectName("l_fell")
        self.l_pres = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_pres.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 83, 123, 20))
        self.l_pres.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(123, 19))
        self.l_pres.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(123, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.l_pres.setFont(font)
        self.l_pres.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.l_pres.setObjectName("l_pres")
        self.l_wind = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_wind.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(246, 83, 123, 20))
        self.l_wind.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(123, 19))
        self.l_wind.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(123, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.l_wind.setFont(font)
        self.l_wind.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.l_wind.setObjectName("l_wind")
        self.l_temp_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_temp_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-6, 105, 120, 20))
        self.l_temp_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 19))
        self.l_temp_1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(120, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.l_temp_1.setFont(font)
        self.l_temp_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.l_temp_1.setObjectName("l_temp_1")
        self.l_temp_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_temp_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 105, 122, 20))
        self.l_temp_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(122, 19))
        self.l_temp_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(122, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.l_temp_2.setFont(font)
        self.l_temp_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.l_temp_2.setObjectName("l_temp_2")
        self.l_temp_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_temp_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(246, 105, 116, 20))
        self.l_temp_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(116, 19))
        self.l_temp_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(116, 20))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.l_temp_3.setFont(font)
        self.l_temp_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.l_temp_3.setObjectName("l_temp_3")
        self.btn_more = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.btn_more.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-4, 123, 378, 33))
        self.btn_more.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(378, 33))
        self.btn_more.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(378, 33))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Bookman Old Style")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        font.setStrikeOut(True)
        self.btn_more.setFont(font)
        self.btn_more.setStyleSheet("border-color: rgb(198, 198, 198);\n"
"border-color: rgb(160, 160, 160);")
        self.btn_more.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btn_more.setDefault(False)
        self.btn_more.setFlat(False)
        self.btn_more.setObjectName("btn_more")
        self.l_day = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_day.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(4, 132, 111, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.l_day.setFont(font)
        self.l_day.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.l_day.setObjectName("l_day")
        self.l_logo = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.l_logo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 8, 171, 71))
        self.l_logo.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoContextMenu)
        self.l_logo.setText("")
        self.l_logo.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.l_logo.setObjectName("l_logo")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 126, 371, 3))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 130, 384, 411))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.box.setContentsMargins(4, 0, 2, 0)
        self.box.setSpacing(0)
        self.box.setObjectName("box")
        self.l_temp.raise_()
        self.l_city.raise_()
        self.l_type.raise_()
        self.l_fell.raise_()
        self.l_pres.raise_()
        self.l_wind.raise_()
        self.l_temp_1.raise_()
        self.l_temp_2.raise_()
        self.l_temp_3.raise_()
        self.l_logo.raise_()
        self.line.raise_()
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.raise_()
        self.btn_more.raise_()
        self.l_day.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.l_temp.setText(_translate("Form", "-27 C"))
        self.l_city.setText(_translate("Form", "City"))
        self.l_type.setText(_translate("Form", "type weather"))
        self.l_fell.setText(_translate("Form", "0 C"))
        self.l_pres.setText(_translate("Form", "750"))
        self.l_wind.setText(_translate("Form", "3 м/с"))
        self.l_temp_1.setText(_translate("Form", "ощущается"))
        self.l_temp_2.setText(_translate("Form", "давление мм.р.ст."))
        self.l_temp_3.setText(_translate("Form", "скорость ветра"))
        self.btn_more.setText(_translate("Form", "_____"))
        self.l_day.setText(_translate("Form", "воскресеьне"))
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложение не запускается при отсутствии подключения к интернету.
Показывает ошибку
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @ivapop я добавил обновление в новый ответ. проверьте.

Answer (score 1):

```
class WeatherData(QThread):
    req = weather.today()
```

Вот тут ошибка. Класс не инициализируется без первого запроса!

Выстави умолчания совместимого типа:

```
class WeatherData(QThread):
    req = {} # тут можно None
    temp = 0
    #и тд..
```

Оно в интерфейсе покажет 0, и через мгновение обновится. Начни с этого.

Дальше напиши стек с виджетом "загрузка" и поставь его пока  `not req` выше погоды. Потом изучай на сигналы-слоты - это основа qt.

Comment: А как реализовать стек?

Comment: я про виджет https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html

Answer (score 1):

**ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ ОТВЕТА.**

> Приложение **`не запускается при отсутствии подключения к интернету`**.
>
> Показывает ошибку `TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable`

**UPDATE**

**main.py**

```
import sys
import datetime

from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtTest, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

import weather
from weather import DAYS 

# +++ pyuic5 root.ui -o root_ui.py -x
from root_ui import Ui_Form                              

#два класса с числами Фобаначе , для правного визуала 
H_show = [
    155, 156, 157, 158,
    160, 168, 181, 202,
    236, 291, 380, 400,
    440, 500, 535,
]
H_hide = [
    155, 156, 157, 158,
    160, 168, 181, 202,
    236, 291, 380, 400,
    440, 500, 535,
]

class WeatherData(QThread):
    req = weather.today()
    mySignal = pyqtSignal() 

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
    if req:                                                  # !!! 
        temp = req['temp']
        feels = req['feels']
        pres = req['pressure']
        speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
        city = req['city']
        type = req['dis']
        week = weather.week()
        flag = True
    else:
        flag = False
        temp = ''
        feels = None
        pres = None
        speed = ''
        city = None
        type = None
        week = []
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
# !        while True:
        while self.flag:                                        # !!! 
            req = weather.today()
            req_week = weather.week()
            
            if req_week and req:            
                self.week = req_week
                self.temp = req['temp']
                self.feels = req['feels']
                self.pres = req['pressure']
                self.speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
                self.city = req['city']
                self.type = req['dis']
            else:
                self.mySignal.emit()
            self.msleep(1000 * 7) # 1000 * 60 * 30 = 1800сек = 30мин
            print(f'def run(self): работает.')   
            
        self.mySignal.emit()                                    # !!!


class MyRoot(QWidget, Ui_Form): 
    def __init__(self):            
        super().__init__()        
        self.setupUi(self)         


class App(QWidget):
    show_more = True 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weather = WeatherData()
        self.weather.mySignal.connect(self._error) 
        self.weather.start()
        
        self.set()
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        if self.weather.flag:                                     # !!!
            self.setData()
            self.setMore()
            
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()                              # !!!
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateTime)               # !!!
        self.timer.setInterval(3000)   
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.timer.start)
        
    def updateTime(self): 
        if self.weather.flag:
            return
        req = weather.today()            
        if req:
            self.weather.temp = req['temp']
            self.weather.feels = req['feels']
            self.weather.pres = req['pressure']
            self.weather.speed = str(req['wind']['speed'])
            self.weather.city = req['city']
            self.weather.type = req['dis']
            self.weather.week = weather.week()

            self.set()
            self.setData()
            self.setMore()
            
            self.weather.flag = True            
            self.weather.start()
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        
    def _error(self):                        
        print(f'\n"Проверьте доступ в интернет !!!"\n')
        self.weather.flag = False                                 # !!!    

    def set(self):
#        self.w_root = uic.loadUi('root.ui')
        self.w_root = MyRoot()
        self.w_root.show()                    
        self.w_root.btn_more.clicked.connect(self.setHeight)

    #устанавливаем значение на сегодня
    def setData(self):
        self.w_root.l_temp.setText(str(self.weather.temp) + '°C')
        self.w_root.l_fell.setText(self.weather.feels)
        self.w_root.l_pres.setText(self.weather.pres)
        self.w_root.l_wind.setText(self.weather.speed + 'м/с')
        self.w_root.l_city.setText(self.weather.city)
        self.w_root.l_type.setText(self.weather.type)
        # иконка погоды
        px_logo = QPixmap(f'Ok.png')
        self.w_root.l_logo.setPixmap(px_logo)
        # день недели
        today = DAYS[datetime.datetime.today().weekday()]
        self.w_root.l_day.setText(today['title'])
        color = today['color']
        self.w_root.l_day.setStyleSheet(f'color:{color}')

    def setHeight(self):
        if self.w_root.height() >= 300:
            self.show_more = False
        if self.show_more:
            for i in H_hide:
                if self.w_root.height() > i:
                    continue
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                
                QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            self.show_more = False
        else:
            for i in reversed(H_show):
                self.w_root.resize(444, i)
                self.w_root.btn_more.move(0, i-26)
                self.w_root.l_day.move(8,i-18)
                QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
            self.show_more = True
        App.show_more = self.show_more

    def setMore(self):
        for i in self.weather.week:
            w_day = uic.loadUi('day.ui')
            w_day.setObjectName('w_day_' + str(i['num']))
            w_day.l_title.setText(i['title'])
            w_day.l_temp.setText(str(round(i['temp'])) + '°C')
            w_day.l_type.setText(i['type'])
            w_day.l_title.setStyleSheet(
                'color: ' + i['color'] + '; background-color: none; border: none')
            if i['active']:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: 1px solid' + i['color'])
            else:
                w_day.setStyleSheet('border: none')
            self.w_root.box.addWidget(w_day)
        self.w_root.box.addStretch()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = App()
    ex.show
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]